# I would like to know how to access control with GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, go

Is there a way to automatically control access to a specific IP with Google App Engine?
For example, if an API endpoint is accessed 10 times in one minute, it will not accept requests for that IP address.

I understand that GKE and GCE can do the same with Google Load Balancing and GOOGLE CLOUD ARMOR. I want to do this with Google App Engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloud Endpoints with App Engine is a solution.

1. You can set up ESP to authenticate clients [Choosing an Authentication Method](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/authentication-method).
2. Then you can limit the api request by adding a quota to your OpenAPI document [Configuring quotas](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/quotas-configure).

This is an example from official documentation:

> The following example shows how to configure the x-google-quota
>   extension in the 
>       paths section:
>
> ```
> x-google-management:  
>  metrics:
> # Define a metric for read requests.
>  - name: "read-requests"
>    displayName: "Read requests"
>    valueType: INT64
>    metricKind: DELTA   quota:
>  limits:
>    # Define the limit or the read-requests metric.
>    - name: "read-limit"
>      metric: "read-requests"
>      unit: "1/min/{project}"
>      values:
>        STANDARD: 1000 paths:   "/echo":
>  post:
>    description: "Echo back a given message."
>    operationId: "echo"
>    produces:
>    - "application/json"
>    responses:
>      200:
>        description: "Echo"
>        schema:
>          $ref: "#/definitions/echoMessage"
>    parameters:
>    - description: "Message to echo"
>      in: body
>      name: message
>      required: true
>      schema:
>        $ref: "#/definitions/echoMessage"
>    x-google-quota:
>      metricCosts:
>        "read-requests": 1
>    security:
>    - api_key: []
> ```

You can find more about [OpenAPI extensions](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/openapi-extensions)

3. You can use some more advanced techniques [Proof of Work](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_work) to enforce rate limiting without needing to remember IP addresses [SO case](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/353240/what-approach-to-use-to-prevent-multiple-requests-to-api-which-is-exposed-to-pub).

Comment: Thank you for answering in great detail.

I thought that the flow might be as follows.
Set ESP → Set OpenAPI to quota → Set limit for specific action.

I will try it for reference. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I did not try it myself but it looks like there is an API to do it.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/reference/rest/v1/apps.firewall.ingressRules

> To programmatically create firewall rules for your App Engine app, you
>   can use the apps.firewall.ingressRules methods in the Admin API.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I heard about Admin API ingressRules for the first time, so let's check it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Cloud Endpoints with App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-app-engine-standard). You can develop, deploy, and manage APIs on any Google Cloud back end with the help of Cloud Endpoints.

> Cloud Endpoints provides quotas, which let you control the rate at
>   which applications can call your API. Setting a quota allows you to
>   specify usage limits to protect your API from an excessive number of
>   requests from calling applications. The excessive requests might have
>   been caused by a simple typo or from an inefficiently designed system
>   that makes needless calls to your API. Regardless of the cause,
>   blocking traffic from a specific source once it reaches a certain
>   level is necessary for the overall health of your API. By setting a
>   quota, you ensure that one application cannot negatively impact other
>   applications that use your API.

You can also check [Rate limiting on Apigee Edge](https://docs.apigee.com/api-platform/develop/rate-limiting)

Comment: As others have answered, Cloud Endpoints may be able to restrict usage. I'll give it a try.
Thank you for answering.